# Add new language to postgresql full text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, stemming

Is there any way to add new languages to postgresq full text search?
Where can I read or start from ?

Answer (score 4):

You can look at this [a link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html) from PostgreSQL documentation, where CREATE DICTIONARY commands are listed. There are several types of dictionaries that can be used and added, and commands for adding them deffer.

For example, if you wish to add Ispell dictionary, you would do it like this:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY my_lang_ispell (
    TEMPLATE = ispell,
    DictFile = path_to_my_lang_dict_file,
    AffFile = path_to_my_lang_affixes_file,
    StopWords = path_to_my_lang_astop_words_file
);
```

DictFile and AffFile are files you need to google somewhere, depending on the language you want to add. StopWords file keeps words that should be ignored, I guess you can also find that file on the Internet.