# Where to find Ukrainian 'ispell', 'aspell', 'snowball' dictionary for adding it to full-text search in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, full-text-search, snowball, ispell

After parsing many documents, I have a lot of rows/columns with Ukrainian text that should be indexed for full-text search in Postgres.

I've found that Postgres 14 supports by default [29 languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751892/get-full-list-of-full-text-search-configuration-languages/39752553#39752553), but unfortunately not the Ukrainian one.

After subsequent digging, I've found that it allows [adding an external dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365611/add-new-language-to-postgresql-full-text-search):

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY my_lang_ispell (
    TEMPLATE = ispell,
    DictFile = path_to_my_lang_dict_file,
    AffFile = path_to_my_lang_affixes_file,
    StopWords = path_to_my_lang_astop_words_file
);
```

But how to find the most relevant `DictFile`, `AffFile`, and `StopWords` files?  For example, [snowball](https://snowballstem.org/demo.html) source doesn't contain this language.

So, could anyone help me find the best way to obtain `ispell`, `aspell`, `snowball`, or another dictionary for the Ukrainian language?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you have to create them yourself.

Answer (score 10):

After more deep exploring, found the solution on this resource [dict_uk](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk)

1. Compile files manually by [this guide](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk/tree/master/distr/hunspell):

```bash
sudo snap install gradle

$ cd dict_uk
$ ./gradlew expand

$ cd distr/hunspell/

$ ../../gradlew hunspell

$ sudo cp build/hunspell/uk_UA.aff /usr/share/postgresql/12/tsearch_data/uk_ua.affix
$ sudo cp build/hunspell/uk_UA.dic /usr/share/postgresql/12/tsearch_data/uk_ua.dict
$ sudo cp ../postgresql/ukrainian.stop /usr/share/postgresql/12/tsearch_data/ukrainian.stop
```

Or just download & unzip the latest hunspell-uk_UA_X.X.X.zip from [here](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk/releases) and [stop words file](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk/raw/master/distr/postgresql/ukrainian.stop)

2. Follow the [guide](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk/tree/master/distr/postgresql) of setting up `ukrainian` language in the Postgres:

```bash
$ sudo cp uk_UA.aff $(pg_config --sharedir)/tsearch_data/uk_ua.affix
$ sudo cp uk_UA.dic $(pg_config --sharedir)/tsearch_data/uk_ua.dict
$ sudo cp ukrainian.stop $(pg_config --sharedir)/tsearch_data/ukrainian.stop
```

```sql
$ sudo su postgres
$ psql

CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY ukrainian_huns (TEMPLATE = ispell, DictFile = uk_ua, AffFile = uk_ua, StopWords = ukrainian);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY ukrainian_stem (template = simple, stopwords = ukrainian);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ukrainian (PARSER=default);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ukrainian ALTER MAPPING FOR  hword, hword_part, word WITH ukrainian_huns, ukrainian_stem;

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ukrainian ALTER MAPPING FOR  int, uint, numhword, numword, hword_numpart, email, float, file, url, url_path, version, host, sfloat WITH simple;

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ukrainian ALTER MAPPING FOR asciihword, asciiword, hword_asciipart WITH english_stem;

# \dFd
...
 pg_catalog | english_stem    | snowball stemmer for english language
...
 public     | ukrainian_huns  | 
 public     | ukrainian_stem  |
```

Now it is available for creating a searchable column with help of `to_tsvector`:

```sql
      ALTER TABLE extracted_pages
      ADD COLUMN tsvector_uk tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        setweight(to_tsvector('ukrainian', coalesce(column_with_text, '')), 'A')
      ) STORED;
```

This example shows the correct stemming for the Ukrainian language:

```sql
SELECT to_tsvector('ukrainian', 'солодко дзюрчить джерело і хочеться жити, любити, творити... ');
 => [{"to_tsvector"=>"'джерело':3 'дзюрчати':2 'жити':6 'любити':7 'солодко':1 'творити':8 'хочеться':5"}]
```

#### Results

The Postgres full-text search works as well as similar search text engine [SphinxSearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/) in terms of quality, but it is a bit slower.

On the same query from the huge amount of records (278_000) it returns the same results:

```
Postgres     - ActiveRecord: 67.6ms
SphinxSearch - ActiveRecord: 10.9ms

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
```

Thank you very much, [dict_uk](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk) support team!